# WinForm C# DLL using ListBox - SelectedValueChanged Event firing inconsistently

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am developing a DLL which is loaded into a Tab page in a Enteprise application.

A ListBox control (single select) has an event on listBox_SelectedValueChanged where the use choosed between different "Display Styles" which when changes fires a sub-routine to reload a DataViewGrid control with different information. Code is below for this:

```
private void listBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("LBSVC Value:" + listBoxDisplayStyles.SelectedValue + " -- Index:" + listBoxDisplayStyles.SelectedIndex);
    if (listBoxDisplayStyles.SelectedValue != null)
        PatientChanged(true); // true = force a refresh           
}
```

Now inconsistently when finished interacting with DGV control (no editing, just scrolling and ToolTip triggering to show extended information on the cells) I move the mouse back over the listbox control and click a different line to. The new listbox line becomes current (selection bar appears), but the event does not seem to be triggered (ie the MessageBox does not appear and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead. Therein you can still use `listBox.SelectedValue` to fetch current value and act accordingly.

BTW it looks like you're working with more than one `ListBox` here. The event handler uses the object name `listBox` whereas the event body uses `listBoxDisplayStyles`. That might have something to do with the problem you're facing. But first try `SelectedIndexChanged` and let us know.

Comment: Will check that. The Listbox was renamed after the original event routine was written, so the routine still holds the old name.

I have previously tried the SelectedIndexChanged event but saw the same weird behaviour.

cheers,

JonHD

Comment: Actually what I did was remove the code and function and remove the  event from the Designer Properties. I then started from scratch (double clicked on the event in the properties) and pasted in the original code. Now all seems to work fine.